# Laravel Socialite 2.0 Facebook Authentication only returning id and name

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel, laravel-socialite

I am using Laravel's Socialite package (version 2.0.0). It is working great for google and github but when I try to login with facebook, I get this:

```
ErrorException in FacebookProvider.php line 89:
Undefined index: first_name
```

In the `FacebookProvider.php` the error is from this method:

```
protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
{
    return (new User)->setRaw($user)->map([
        'id' => $user['id'], 'nickname' => null, 'name' => $user['first_name'].' '.$user['last_name'],
        'email' => isset($user['email']) ? $user['email'] : null, 'avatar' => $this->graphUrl.'/'.$this->version.'/'.$user['id'].'/picture?type=normal',
    ]);
}
```

If I `dd()` the `$user` param before this mapping. I only get id and the name of the authenticated Facebook user. So, it means that I am not getting the email of the Facebook user. I at least need `name` and `email` of the user.

After `dd()` this method looks like this:

```
protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
{
    dd($user);
    return (new User)->setRaw($user)->map([
        'id' => $user['id'], 'nickname' => null, 'name' => $user['first_name'].' '.$user['last_name'],
        'email' => isset($user['email']) ? $user['email'] : null, 'avatar' => $this->graphUrl.'/'.$this->version.'/'.$user['id'].'/picture?type=normal',
    ]);
}
```

What could be the problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated to the latest version of Socialite. Now it works!

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem and is a bug! use the new version of file FacebookProvider.php [here](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/2.0/src/Two/FacebookProvider.php) and work!

Answer (score 0):

For thoose who are confused on how to update into the latest version just 
add this into your **composer.json** file.

```
"laravel/socialite": "2.*"
```

and into your terminal ***composer update***

Cheers!