# Laravel Socialite returns error Undefined index: first_name

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-socialite

Using [laravel-socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) I am trying this code

```
$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
```

But it returns error

```
ErrorException in FacebookProvider.php line 90: 
Undefined index: first_name
```

I have `laravel/socialite version ^2.0` required in composer.

How to solve this?

Comment: what are you returning?. try `dd($user)` to check what they it return.

Comment: i am trying to get the user by  `$user = Socialite::driver($type)->user();`. which gives me error. How can I dump $user before that?

Comment: dump it before return statement.

Comment: Sorry I still newbie. the only statement I have in that method is `$user = Socialite::driver($type)->user();` If I dump before this statement I get error undefined variable.

Comment: dumping $user before returning gives me 'name' and 'id'.

Answer (score 3):

I just have to update the new FacbookProivder.php file which I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370907/laravel-socialite-2-0-facebook-authentication-only-returning-id-and-name).

[Here](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/2.0/src/Two/FacebookProvider.php) is the file. courtesy German for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the array of fields that you want to retrieve from facebook by calling the `fields(array $fields)` method of the facebook provider.

Here is an example of that

```
//get the driver and set desired fields
$driver = Socialite::driver('facebook')
                ->fields([
                    'name', 
                    'first_name', 
                    'last_name', 
                    'email', 
                    'gender', 
                    'verified'
                ]);
// retrieve the user
$user = $driver->user();
```

For reference on the fields names: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/