# Laravel socialite facebook scopes

Tags: php, facebook, laravel

when i login by facebook i got error:

> local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined index: first_name'

My controler:

```
public function facebook() {
    return Socialize::with("facebook")->redirect();
}

public function callback() {
    $user = Socialize::with("facebook")->user();
    dd($user);
    return $user;
}
```

I solved it.
I had old version of guzzle 4.0 but new version of socialite need 6.2.
So in first step I removed socialite.
In second step I updated guzzly to 6.2.
And now everything is good :).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370907/laravel-socialite-2-0-facebook-authentication-only-returning-id-and-name

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/socialite

Comment: Ok i changed code in FacebookProvider and i got error  local.ERROR: exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error response [url] https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me?access_token=&appsecret_proof=11f383f2fc2445ac69fda6985be96c8c8e569c82be88eb721265639dd1069d29&fields=name%2Cemail%2Cgender%2Cverified [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request' in /home/szymon/Projekty/skarbonka/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:71